Firth's model stuck (with non-converge warning and CPU usage 99%) in R using the logistf package
Here is the process of creating the datasets. I saved in both rds and csv format in case any internal data characteristics changes during the saving process:
# Save the data frame
saveRDS(train_proc_rds, "train_proc_example1.rds")
fwrite(train_proc_rds, "train_proc_example2.csv")


# reload data frame
train_proc_df1 <- readRDS("train_proc_example1.rds")
train_proc_df2 <- fread("train_proc_example2.csv")


Here are the links to the two sample data (the sample data are not large - only 23 kb, but may be particular that leads to the error):

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZUSQxp9uycL8nRJXBLHUMRADk2KM6eYG?usp=sharing

Here are my codes for running firth's model. There are always warnings of non-convergence and suggested me to increase iteration which does not really help. The bizarre thing is when I run the code it stuck forever but the activity monitor shows 99% CPU usage. Here are the detailed codes:
library(caret)
library(logistf)
library(data.table)


# Define training control
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                              number = 3, repeats = 3,
                              savePredictions = TRUE,
                              classProbs = TRUE)

# Define the custom model function
firth_model <- list(
  type = "Classification",
  library = "logistf",
  loop = NULL,
  parameters = data.frame(parameter = c("none"), class = c("character"), label = c("none")),
  grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
    data.frame(none = "none")
  },
  fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) {
    data <- as.data.frame(x)
    data$group <- y
    logistf(group ~ ., data = data, control = logistf.control(maxit = 100), ...)
  },
  predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
    as.factor(ifelse(predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response") > 0.5, "AD", "control"))
  },
  prob = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
    preds <- predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response")
    data.frame(control = 1 - preds, AD = preds)
  }
)


when I ran model 2 with the second dataset it replicated my issue:

# Training the model
set.seed(123)
model1 <- train(train_proc_df1[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("AD", "group")],
                            train_proc_df1$group,
                            method = firth_model,
                            trControl = train.control)
print(model1)


here is the most recent error
model2 <- train(train_proc_df2[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("AD", "group")],
+                 train_proc_df2$group,
+                             method = firth_model,
+                             trControl = train.control)
+ Fold1.Rep1: none=none 
Warning in logistf(group ~ ., data = data, control = logistf.control(maxit = 100),  :
  Nonconverged PL confidence limits: maximum number of iterations for variables: (Intercept), x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24 exceeded. Try to increase the number of iterations by passing 'logistpl.control(maxit=...)' to parameter plcontrol
- Fold1.Rep1: none=none 
+ Fold2.Rep1: none=none 
Warning in logistf(group ~ ., data = data, control = logistf.control(maxit = 100),  :
  Nonconverged PL confidence limits: maximum number of iterations for variables: (Intercept), x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24 exceeded. Try to increase the number of iterations by passing 'logistpl.control(maxit=...)' to parameter plcontrol
- Fold2.Rep1: none=none 
+ Fold3.Rep1: none=none 
Warning in logistf(group ~ ., data = data, control = logistf.control(maxit = 100),  :
  Nonconverged PL confidence limits: maximum number of iterations for variables: (Intercept), x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24 exceeded. Try to increase the number of iterations by passing 'logistpl.control(maxit=...)' to parameter plcontrol
- Fold3.Rep1: none=none 
+ Fold1.Rep2: none=none 
Warning in logistf(group ~ ., data = data, control = logistf.control(maxit = 100),  :
  logistf.fit: Maximum number of iterations for full model exceeded. Try to increase the number of iterations or alter step size by passing 'logistf.control(maxit=..., maxstep=...)' to parameter control


ignore the warning parts, the model seems to stuck on the 3rd fold forever (and it appears to be running because the activity monitor shows CPU usage of 99%). When I ran model 1, the same issue seemed to persist.


R.version
               _                           
platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20      
arch           aarch64                     
os             darwin20                    
system         aarch64, darwin20           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2023                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        85441                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
nickname       Eye Holes   

Here is my package version:
> packageVersion("caret")
[1] ‘6.0.94’
> packageVersion("logistf")
[1] ‘1.26.0’
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.10’


Do we need to do this first? names(train_proc)[25] <- "group"

if you read the error message, it suggests that you "Try to increase the number of iterations by passing 'logistpl.control(maxit=...)' to parameter plcontrol". Did you do that?

Apologize @Edward . The earlier dataset actually did not replicate my issue, something was wrong in the data saving process and I think I fixed it with the new datasets. Iteration does not seem to be the major issue as it's a warning not an error: I tried the earlier dataset with just 100 iterations, it ran just fine. The real issue is something internal of the dataset that makes the model stuck.

If you increase the number of iterations, as suggested by the warning message, you should get the desired results.
train_proc <- data.table::fread("train_proc.csv")
names(train_proc)[25] <- "group"  # missing from your code

set.seed(123)
firth.logist.model <- train(train_proc[, .SD, .SDcols = !"group"],
                            train_proc$group,
                            method = firth_model,
                            trControl = train_control,
                            plcontrol=logistpl.control(maxit=1000))

print(firth.logist.model)


53 samples
24 predictors
 2 classes: 'AD', 'control' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 35, 36, 35, 36, 35, 35, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy   Kappa     
  0.4270153  -0.1482292

Tuning parameter 'none' was held constant at a value of none


Thanks! My earlier dataset actually did not replicate the issue that the model could run smoothly. Would you mind trying the two new datasets and help check the real issue?

I get an error: "Error: object 'train.control' not found"

I fixed the typo. How about now?
